# delayed_job on MySQL: 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Trying to deploy a Rails 3 app in a MySQL environment, but am running into a problem with the `delayed_job` (v3.0.5) gem.

The `db:migrate` seems to go OK:

```
==  CreateDelayedJobs: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:delayed_jobs, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0055s
-- add_index(:delayed_jobs, [:priority, :run_at], {:name=>"delayed_jobs_priority"})
   -> 0.0040s
==  CreateDelayedJobs: migrated (0.0096s) =====================================
```

but trying `script/delayed_job run` (very long query warning):

```
delayed_job: process with pid 10713 started.
Mysql2::Error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery': UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `locked_at` = '2013-02-11 10:43:13', `locked_by` = 'delayed_job                       host:dev pid:10713' WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`id` IN (SELECT  id FROM `delayed_jobs`  WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-02-11 10:43:13' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-02-11 06:4                      3:13') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:dev pid:10713') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) AND ((run_at <= '2013-02-11 10:43:13' AND (l                      ocked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-02-11 06:43:13') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:dev pid:10713') AND failed_at IS NULL)
```

I can confirm that the tables are all there and are empty.

I have tried: MySQL 5.1 and 5.5 as well as Percona and MariaDB of each. I have tried on both Linux and Windows machines.

It is mind boggling to me that this works fine on sqlite3 but not MySQL. Given the gem's popularity I am hoping that I am making a mistake somewhere rather than the possibility that its broken on MySQL.

Thanks.

--

I've tested in Postgres 9.1 and it works fine ...

Comment: *It is mind boggling to me that ... MySQL [doesn't work]* SQL Server and/or Oracle developer who expects their RDBMS to support SQL, I see.

Comment: Are you running an up to date version of delayed_job ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung It would seem so (v3.0.5 in Gemfile.lock), I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and found this.  It seems you need to use an older version for now.  They did a few updates yesterday to the active record gem.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/issues/32

Comment: Thanks, checked in issues but it seems I was looking in the wrong gem. Glad to see it'll be sorted soon.